# What does this mean; /127.0.0.1:61720 => /127.0.0.1:1935] CLOSED

Tags: android, server, red5, screensharing

I'm trying to do screen share using red5. I open the client side app using the jnlp file. When I start sharing I'm getting this:

`[INFO] [New I/O client worker #1-1] org.redfire.screen.ScreenClientHandler - cha
nnel closed: [id: 0x01b272d9, /127.0.0.1:61720 => /127.0.0.1:1935] CLOSED`

I want to know what the `/127.0.0.1:61720 => /127.0.0.1:1935` means.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the socket connection from 127.0.0.1:61720 to 127.0.0.1:1935 has been closed.